# Python OpenCV: How to convert YCbCr back to RGB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

In OpenCV (Python), to convert RGB to YCbCr we use:

```
imgYCC = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
```

What if i want to come back to RGB?

Comment: `cv2.cvtColor(imgYCC, cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR)`

Answer (score 5):

Check the [docs for color conversions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html). You can see *all* of the available color conversion codes here: [Conversion Color Codes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0).

For the colorspaces available, you can generally transform both ways---`COLOR_BGR2YCrCb` (i.e. BGR-to-YCrCb) and `COLOR_YCrCb2BGR` (i.e. YCrCb-to-BGR). Also, OpenCV uses BGR ordering, not RGB ordering. Regardless, to answer the specific question at hand, simply convert back using the opposite order of the colorspaces:

```
img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(imgYCC, cv2.COLOR_YCrCb2BGR)
```

Note: `cv2.COLOR_YCrCb2BGR` is equivalent to `cv2.COLOR_YCR_CB2BGR`, I just find the first variant easier to read. Since these transformations (on `uint8` images especially), there's some rounding going on so you won't necessarily get the *exact* same image going back and fourth. But you shouldn't be more than like 1 off at a few of the locations.

Comment: This should really be emphasised:  "Also, OpenCV uses BGR ordering, not RGB ordering"